# how to solve this in asp.net why result = 0

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

Why result is zero? I need result 0.5

```
public HttpResponseMessage Atendence(string sid)
{
    double res = 2 / 4;                 
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK,res);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It will help

double res = (double)2 / 4;

Answer (score 0):

`2` and `4` are both integers, so this calculation will be performed as an integer operation, returning 0, then being cast to a double. Make them `2.0` and `4.0` and see if that helps.